# File download works from g:link but doesn't work from g:imageButton

Tags: grails

I need to change a file download "button" from a g:link to a g:imageButton.  They both call the same method in the controller with the same parameters.  The g:link and g:imageButton both execute the same code with the same parameters so far as I can tell.  The new g:imageButton doesn't give me a csv file download, however.  It executes without any problems, but doesn't create the file download.

Both use GET.  The g:link (which works) gives this message in the console:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv:
```

Why would changing from a g:link to a g:imageButton cause the file download to stop working?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the g:imageButton tag come from?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to say. But this message get's a lot of results in google search...

Comment: g:imageButton is used in the legacy code.  It must be from Grails 1.  It still works (except for downloading), but it's not in the Grails 2 docs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use g:actionSubmitImage.  g:imageButton isn't in the grails 2 docs, but it works in other places in our code base that are not doing file downloads.